# *ngFor hide on click

Tags: angular, hide, ngfor

I have a problem trying to hide some divs.

Code:

**example.component.html**

```
<div class="allCompanies"  [@listAnimation]="companies.lenght">
  <div id="{{i}}" class="company" *ngFor="let comp of companies; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="show" class="card" id="card">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <p>
            <strong>Name: </strong>{{comp.name}}</p>
          <p>
            <strong>Data: </strong>{{comp.data}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="btnDiv col-sm-4">
          <button class="btn login" (click)="showLogin($event, i)">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I do to, when I click on one button, make the element clicked stay visible on the page and make the others dissapear?

Thank you all!

Comment: You can do this: (1) define `selectedComp` in the code (with the appropriate type), (2) when you click on an item, do `(click)="selectedComp = comp"`, (3) filter with `*ngIf="!selectedComp || selectedComp === comp"`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan almost haha, this behaviour does that the element that dissapear is the one clicked and show the others, I want exactly the opossite, mantain the clickd, and hide de others. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know how you can get that result. The expression in `*ngIf` should evaluate to `true` only for the selected component, or if `selectedComp` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do that. This is the one of many. You can implement filtering of empresas array when you click on a button.
Do something like this: in showLogin($event, i)  function you can remove elements
of empresas array that are not clicked

```
<button class="btn login" (click)="showLogin($event, i)">Entrar</button>
```

in your .ts file:

```
showLogin($event, index) {
    for (let k = 0; k < this.empressas.length; k++) {
        if (k != index) {
            this.empressas.slice(k,1);
        }
    }
}
```

this way, now in your epressas array you will have just one element, the element that you clicked on, and it will be rendered only one element. Like i mentioned, this is one of probably many ways to solve this problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: Completely agree, but if I work with the slice I have the problem that if I regret to choose that option, and I go one step back, my array has lost all the other elements no?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. There must be a way to save that starting array in some helper variable, so when you filter empressas array you don't loose initial data... And then when you regret choosing that option, when you get back , you reinstantiate empressas variable like this.empressas = this.helperVariableEmpressas

Comment: How do you go back? Is there a button that you can click on that gets you in previous state (beginning state) ? If that's the case, you just need to put click event listener on that button with method on it . In that method you can refresh empressas variable and  start from scratch: this.empressas = this.helperVariableEmpressas

Comment: I am not doing it actually, but maybe further I develop it hahaha. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Not a problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this, remove the i parameter from the showLogin function:

```
<div class="allCompanies"  [@listAnimation]="empresas.lenght">
  <div id="{{i}}" class="empresa" *ngFor="let comp of empresas; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="show" class="card" id="card">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <p>
            <strong>Name: </strong>{{comp.name}}</p>
          <p>
            <strong>Data: </strong>{{comp.data}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="btnDiv col-sm-4">
          <button class="btn login" (click)="showLogin($event)">Entrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your Controller set the classes to the elements, all the .card to card-hide and the parent of the clicked element to card-show:

```
showLogin = function (event) {

    var target = event.target;
    var pElement = target.parentElement.parentElement;
    var pclassAttr = pElement.attributes.class;
    var cardElems = angular.element( document.querySelector('.card'));
    cardElems.addClass('card-hide');
    pElement.classList.remove('card-hide');
    pElement.classList.add('card-show');
}
```

So in your CSS file you should have those selectors to hide and show respectively. I hope it works.

For more info about the add and remove methods check out this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm using angular 4 :S. Thank you anyyway for take you time to answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. So then you can use the [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) class. It's a helper to manipulate the DOM elements. Once imported and assigned in the constructor   constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { } 
You can use it like this: 
 this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'color', 'blue');

Answer (score 0):

I've sudo-coded the solution below, essentially you'll need to either use a service or wrap the child items your iterating through in another component. You'll then need to use ngClass or ngStyle to hide the items with the hidden property set to false bar the one you clicked on.

Check this out:

```
 export class ListHandlerService {
    public myList: any[];

    constructor() {
        this.myList = [
            {
                name: 'bob',
                hidden: false
            },
            {
                name: 'john',
                hidden: false
            }
        ]//whatever your list is
    }

    hideOthers(name: any) {
        let newList = this.myList.map((object) => {
            if (object.name !== name) {
                return object.hidden = true
            }
        })
        this.myList = newList;
    }
}


export class ItemComponent {
    public name: string;
    public hidden: boolean = false;
    constructor(private myListHandler: ListHandlerService) { }

    onClick() {
        this.myListHandler.hideOthers(this.name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a more simple solution.

```
 <div *ngIf="show[i]" class="card" id="card"> //Change show to show[i]
```

in your ts file add:

```
show = [];

showLogin(event: any, index: any){
   this.show[index] = !this.show[index];
}
```

Comment: The OP asked to for the clicked element to "stay visible on the page and make the others disappear?". Your solution toggles each individual element.

Comment: @DimitriosK. you are right.  I missed the question.